# Need to know where the location of PHP-extensions and others

Tags: php, php-fpm

I need to know where I can find the location of the list below :

## include_path            = /path/PHP-pear/

## extension_dir           = /path/PHP-extensions/

## mime_magic.magicfile     = /path/PHP-magic.mime

I installed php using remi repo and I need to know how to disable and enable the modules too.

Thanks

Comment: You can use php.ini to enable/disable any modules. You can find  location of the file in the output of phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php-7.2 -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -E '(include_path|extension_dir|mime_magic.magicfile)'
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php-7.2/modules => /usr/local/lib/php-7.2/modules
include_path => .:/pear/lib:/var/www/pear/lib => .:/pear/lib:/var/www/pear/lib
```

See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Configuration_Cheat_Sheet

FYI, you can change a lot of things in PHP-FPM per pool as well.